# Crystal Reports .Net 4 Beta 2 Production Exception

Tags: crystal-reports, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I have an application that generates some pretty basic reports. I have installed the crystal reports .net 4 beta 2 for visual studio 2010 and copied the DLLs into my web site's bin folder. Everything works fine when running locally but when I try to create a report on my production server I get the following exception thrown.

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{C0D87D96-8D57-4274-AA18-D465E31F901E} failed due to the following error: 
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
[COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID     
{C0D87D96-8D57-4274-AA18-D465E31F901E} failed due to the following error: 80040154 
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +141

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for     
'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.]
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +0
view_report.UpdateReport(Object sender, EventArgs e) +120
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112


System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

I haven't done a whole lot with crystal reports so there may be something I am missing, but I had to manually copy the DLLs from my GAC into my applications bin folder because I didn't want to run the installer on production. Everything worked locally when I removed the dll loads from my web.config so my site would look in Bin for any additional dlls but I don't know why it is going wrong.

Anyone have any insight?

EDIT:

I also have installed the runtime for deployment on the server as well to see if that was an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after contacting the crystal reports users on their forums it looks like you can only have the .net 4 runtime installed on your production machine, as this was unfeasible for me I had to migrate down to 3.5 to get everything working.